# Create a Location in Windows where I have full read and write access

Tags: windows-7, windows, user-accounts, accessibility

As it happens I got a chance to work for a company where every developer gets a Window desktop to work on, without giving the admin rights to run things as Admin. On that I tried installing "Spring Tool Suite" and after Installing that I tried starting the embedded server "Pivotal tc Server Developer Edition v3.0".

But I got the following error message :-

```
  Publishing the configuration...
   Error copying file to C:/Users/sts-bundle/pivotal-tc-server-developer-3.0.2.SR2/base-instance/backup\catalina.policy: C:\Users\sts-bundle\pivotal-tc-server-developer-3.0.2.SR2\base-instance\conf\catalina.policy (The system cannot find the path specified) C:\Users\sts-bundle\pivotal-tc-server-developer-3.0.2.SR2\base-instance\conf\catalina.policy (The system cannot find the path specified)
   Error copying file to C:/Users/sts-bundle/pivotal-tc-server-developer-3.0.2.SR2/base-instance/backup\catalina.properties: C:\Users\sts-bundle\pivotal-tc-server-developer-3.0.2.SR2\base-instance\conf\catalina.properties (The system cannot find the path specified)
   C:\Users\sts-bundle\pivotal-tc-server-developer-3.0.2.SR2\base-instance\conf\catalina.properties (The system cannot find the path specified)
   Error copying file to C:/Users/sts-bundle/pivotal-tc-server-developer-3.0.2.SR2/base-instance/backup\context.xml: C:\Users\sts-bundle\pivotal-tc-server-developer-3.0.2.SR2\base-instance\conf\context.xml (The system cannot find the path specified)
   C:\Users\sts-bundle\pivotal-tc-server-developer-3.0.2.SR2\base-instance\conf\context.xml (The system cannot find the path specified)
   Error copying file to C:/Users/sts-bundle/pivotal-tc-server-developer-3.0.2.SR2/base-instance/backup\jmxremote.access: C:\Users\sts-bundle\pivotal-tc-server-developer-3.0.2.SR2\base-instance\conf\jmxremote.access (The system cannot find the path specified)
   C:\Users\sts-bundle\pivotal-tc-server-developer-3.0.2.SR2\base-instance\conf\jmxremote.access (The system cannot find the path specified)
   Error copying file to C:/Users/sts-bundle/pivotal-tc-server-developer-3.0.2.SR2/base-instance/backup\jmxremote.password: C:\Users\sts-bundle\pivotal-tc-server-developer-3.0.2.SR2\base-instance\conf\jmxremote.password (The system cannot find the path specified)
   C:\Users\sts-bundle\pivotal-tc-server-developer-3.0.2.SR2\base-instance\conf\jmxremote.password (The system cannot find the path specified)
   Error copying file to C:/Users/sts-bundle/pivotal-tc-server-developer-3.0.2.SR2/base-instance/backup\server.xml: C:\Users\sts-bundle\pivotal-tc-server-developer-3.0.2.SR2\base-instance\conf\server.xml (The system cannot find the path specified)
   C:\Users\sts-bundle\pivotal-tc-server-developer-3.0.2.SR2\base-instance\conf\server.xml (The system cannot find the path specified)
   Error copying file to C:/Users/sts-bundle/pivotal-tc-server-developer-3.0.2.SR2/base-instance/backup\tomcat-users.xml: C:\Users\sts-bundle\pivotal-tc-server-developer-3.0.2.SR2\base-instance\conf\tomcat-users.xml (The system cannot find the path specified)
   C:\Users\sts-bundle\pivotal-tc-server-developer-3.0.2.SR2\base-instance\conf\tomcat-users.xml (The system cannot find the path specified)
   Error copying file to C:/Users/sts-bundle/pivotal-tc-server-developer-3.0.2.SR2/base-instance/backup\web.xml: C:\Users\sts-bundle\pivotal-tc-server-developer-3.0.2.SR2\base-instance\conf\web.xml (The system cannot find the path specified)
   C:\Users\sts-bundle\pivotal-tc-server-developer-3.0.2.SR2\base-instance\conf\web.xml (The system cannot find the path specified)
```

Here the embedded tc server is not able to create the appropriate instances of server by creating the required files.

It was recommended that I install Spring Tool Suite into a location that I have full read/write access.

Is is possible to create a folder in windows wherein I have the aforementioned access.

There is little chance that I will be given admin rights for the system. In this scenario how to do that, I mean how to create a location in my system wherein Spring-Tool Suite could function properly?

Comment: I found here that running the program as admin fixes the problem http://fczaja.blogspot.com/2011/07/error-starting-tc-server-in-sts-27.html   But I dont think the company has a policy to grant admin rights to everyone.

Comment: If the company dosent you could still use a local virtual maschine to test/use stuff you need to do with admin rights.

Comment: It is very likely that you cannot. while you may be able to change the install location to point to a folder upon which you have full control, files are not the only thing that require admin for write access. For instance most installers write the location of the uninstaller to the windows registry so it can be picked up by the Add/Remove software applet. Many applications run other applications and load libraries that may or may not be accessible to the software, or may themselves be configured to run only as admin. In the end, you will not easily be able to bypass those restrictions.